# Add attribute to the recently added input field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which is hidden.

```
<div id="orderFields" style="display: none;">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody id="more-tr">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-weight: bold">Offer</th>
        <td class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="offer" placeholder="Offer title" value="" novalidate>
        </td>
        <th style="font-weight: bold">Image</th>
        <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <img src="" style="max-width:40%;max-height:20%" />
          <input type="file" name="image[]" style="background: transparent;border: transparent">
        </td>
        <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
          <a href="javascript:void(1);" style="width: 10%;">
            <span class="voyager-trash remove-this btn-danger" style="padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have a code to a button that adds the tr field from the hidden field when being clicked.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="addMore" style="float: right;">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span>Add offer(s)</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

And the javascript is the following :

```
$("#addMore").on("click", function() {
  $(".multipleDiv").after($('#orderFields #more-tr').html());
});
```

The button and tr work perfectly but while submitting a form I am getting data from the div that is hidden. So, I removed the attribute from the div which is hidden. Now, I want to add a name attribute to the input field that is just added after clicking the button. But, again I don't want to add an attribute to the input field of an input tag which is hidden.

How can I achieve that?
Also, Why am I not getting data coming from the `<input type="file" name="image">` which is inside the form tag

Comment: which field do you want to add the name attribute? is it the text field or file?

Comment: It is a text field whose id is offer. I tried `$(#offer).attr('name', 'offer[]')`. But the code adds a name attribute to the hidden div as well.

Comment: That's not possible since ID's must be unique and `$(#offer)` can only ever represent one element. What is `$(".multipleDiv")`? no element with that class shown

Comment: It would help if you would provide a runnable [mcve]. Click on `<>` in question editor and you can make it runnable here in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `clone()` and then use the `find()` to get the input with id `offer`. Then use the `attr()` to set the attribute.

```js
$("#addMore").on("click", function() {
  let clone = $('#orderFields #more-tr').clone();
  let offer = clone.find('input[type="text"]');
  offer.attr('name', 'newOffer'); // replace with your value
  offer.attr('id', new Date().getTime()); // ID needs to be unique
  $(".multipleDiv").append(clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="orderFields" style="display: none;">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody id="more-tr">
      <tr>
        <th style="font-weight: bold">Offer</th>
        <td class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <input type="text" class="form-control price" id="offer" placeholder="Offer title" value="" novalidate>
        </td>
        <th style="font-weight: bold">Image</th>
        <td class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
          <img src="" style="max-width:40%;max-height:20%" />
          <input type="file" name="image[]" style="background: transparent;border: transparent">
        </td>
        <td class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12">
          <a href="javascript:void(1);" style="width: 10%;">
            <span class="voyager-trash remove-this btn-danger" style="padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px;"></span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table class="multipleDiv"></table>

<div class="col-md-12">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="addMore" style="float: right;">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> <span>Add offer(s)</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Still wacky putting table elements that aren't `<table>` in a `<div>`

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean? i think things are inside `<td>` which is acceptable

Comment: What I mean is `$('#orderFields #more-tr').html()` is `<tr>` elements. `$(".multipleDiv")` sounds like a `<div>` as you had it...`<div></div><tr></tr>` isn't valid

Comment: totally agree, i changed to `table` and `append()`. I reckon now it holds the semantics tight. Thanks @charlietfl

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, class multipleDiv is the class of a div tag

Comment: @Alisha So the code shown in question would put table rows with no `<table>` after a div and that doesn't make sense and isn't valid

Comment: @Alisha you could just clone the first row `let clone = $('#more-tr tr:first').clone();`. This will also alleviate problem of duplicating the `<tbody>` id

Comment: @charlietfl The table is inside the form tag but I am not getting data coming from `<input type=" file " name=" image[] ">`  What can be the possible reasons?

Comment: @Alisha A cloned file input won't include files AFAIK and you can not programmatically set value to a  file input (other than clearing it) for security reasons. User must do the selecting

Comment: @charlietfl the image was not working before cloning